# Accessing variables within IIFE

Tags: javascript, iife

I'm trying to learn module patterns and I've come across this scenario with IIFE and accessing internal variables.

```
var foo = (function () {
    var bar = false;

    function switchbar () {
     if(bar){ bar = false} else { bar = true } ; 
    };

    function show {
      switchbar();
      console.log(bar)
    };

   function noshow {
         switchbar();
         console.log(bar)
   };

   return {

     showTheBar: show,
     hideTheBar: noshow,
     whatIsBar: bar
   }
}());

foo.showTheBar()  //true
foo.whatIsBar //false  --> should be true
```

Why isn't bar true in the last output? Any insight would help alot. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You've assigned the value of `bar` to `whatIsBar` (`false` at that time) in the return value, it won't automagically change when you change the variable value in `foo` afterwards.

Comment: Your `switchbar` method only switches `bar` if it is undefined, not if it is false. `foo.whatIsBar` is false not because the property is undefined, but because you haven't switched its boolean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value of `bar` is assigned to the variable `whatIsBar` when the foo IIFE is executed. This new variable is no longer related to the value of the original `bar`.

So whaterver `bar` is changed to, it wont affect `whatIsBar`. It is a completely different variable.

Comment: Thanks. I changed whatIsBar to function () { return bar } and I was able to access bar.